# How do i directly write in my ERC721 parent's private mapping?

Tags: erc-721, inheritance

MyContract is ERC721

I want to adapt the _update function to a specific usecase.

In order to keep its core functionality, the adapted function needs to write into _owners, _balances and _tokenApprovals.

Could someone please show me the way?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have implemented to this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I imported ERC 721 and changed the above mentioned mappings from "private" to "internal". this way i can access those variables directly